# How can i repeat a list using the item $index?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list in angular with ng-repeat but i just want to repeat the items that match with the $index, i have something like:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index == item.id">
```

Comment: maybe i understand the question wrong.But in order to set $index you first have to run ng-repeat.$index is the key that ng-repeat process  items in you example.So $index doent exist until you run ng-repeat.

Comment: This probably won't work. You're better off using a filter to filter the items before they are processed by ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

in view

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="item in displayItems">
```

in controller

```
$scope.displayItems = angular.forEach($scope.items, function(_item) {
    // do  the filtering here...
});
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter()` would probably be more appropriate. Not sure what you can return from inside `forEach` that will work as shown

Answer (score 1):

You could just filter prior to the ng-repeat in your controller like so:

```
$scope.filteredItems = $scope.items.filter(function(element, index) {
     return element.id === index 

})
```